# Unexpected field changes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I've developed a series of plugins for QGIS, with one of them specifically designed to import pertinent data from my database into QGIS.

I have successfully retrieved all necessary information, including all layers, data, styles, and so on.

Upon verifying my field names, I found they correspond correctly to my specifications. To illustrate, consider the layer named **ZANRO**. This layer contains the fields **COMMUNE** and **REF_NRO**, as intended.

[image]

However, after the process of saving, closing, and subsequently reopening, I observe a complete alteration in my fields.

[image]

Upon inspecting the .qml file to validate the correct naming of the fields, I confirmed that they were indeed labeled correctly.

However, I'm currently at a loss as to why these issues are occurring. Any insights or suggestions on potential debugging steps or actions that I should take to resolve this problem?

Comment: how do you store data ? geopackage ? shapefile ? database ? It looks like Qgis is not able to correctly save your data and restore the datasource afterward

Comment: @Maximilienjaffrès I store every information inside my phpmyadmin, and when I fecth data I aswell, create the shapefiles as shown in PyQGIS docs

Comment: you should look with some SQL what are the column name in your MySql instance (behind phpmyadmin which is a client of MySql if I am not mistaken). Then check in your shapefile what are raw names of column. .qml is just a style that you apply on your data to give columns (attributes) a label. you can also check in Qgis the datasource in information to check what is really loaded in your .qgs project (.shp or db data). Something is wrong somewhere in your process , and you probably duplicate information with shapefile + database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. For some reason it was using some hidden shapefiles that were not the ones that I was creating.

I deleted that shapes, created my project again from my database data and now it works.